# Применение Repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ado.net, repository, dapper

Всем привет.

Скажите, пожалуйста, по поводу Repository. Когда является хорошая практика использование этого паттерна?

EF + REP не сильно имеет смысл, так как у EF уже есть свой репоз. А например при использовании ADO  или Dapper - есть смысл писать под них REP?

Comment: "Репозиторий и единица рабочих шаблонов (корявый перевод UoW - Unit of Works) предназначены для создания уровня абстракции между уровнем доступа к данным и уровнем бизнес-логики приложения. Реализация таких шаблонов позволяет изолировать приложение от изменений в хранилище данных и упрощает автоматическое модульное тестирование или разработку на основе тестирования." - взято [отсюда](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

Comment: @XelaNimed Это конечно понятно. Вопрос всё же стоял не в том, что это за шаблон. А в том, удачная ли идея писать его под EF, ADO или Dapper ?

Comment: Применение репозитория (с абсолютно любой технологией под капотом, будь то EF, Dapper или чистый ADO.NET) позволяет легко делать модульное тестирование, а также легко менять эту технологию: например, EF стал не устраивать по производительности или возможностям - поменяли его на linq2db, или вообще реляционную СУБД поменяли на NoSQL.

Comment: То есть, если нет твёрдой уверенности в том, какое хранилище окажется оптимальным, то можно подумать о паттерне репозиторий.